# Is the order of evaluation for initialization lists in constructors fixed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, operator-precedence

I was under the impression that the following is prone to leaks

```
class Something {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    std::unique_ptr<int> b{new int{3}};
    std::unique_ptr<C> c;
public:
    Something() : a{new A{}}, c{new C{}} {};
};
```

if the order of evaluation was the following

1. `new A{}`
2. `new int{3}`
3. `new C{}`
4. `a{}`
5. `b{}`
6. `c{}`

I was taking a look at the new C++17 feature (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) that fixes order of evaluation faults in previous versions of C++, but it only seems to talk about function argument evaluations.

I took a look at the cppreference documentation on order of evaluation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and it does not seem to mention this either.

Does the above have a well defined order of evaluation? (either now in C++17 or in previous versions of C++)

Comment: These are different full-expressions.

Comment: @T.C. Updated my question a little.

Comment: @Jarod42 typo.. fixed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that order is not allowed; the language isn't that insane.

These are completely distinct full-expressions, so it's controlled by [[intro.execution]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.execution#16):

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a
>   full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you point me to a location in the standard that says that those are distinct full expressions?

Comment: Thanks!  Could you include that in the answer as well?  Or I can edit it as well

Comment: Also what about the initialization for `b` in my code?  That does not appear to fall under `mem-initializer` as in the link you provided

Comment: It's intended to be covered under *init-declarator*. Doesn't really matter for the purposes of this question, because even if we fall through to the catch-all bullet, the conclusion is the same. (Which is also why I didn't include the full definition of full-expression in the answer; these initializers aren't part of the same expression even by inspection.)

Comment: @HowardHinnant Not for class member initializers. It was never *that* insane.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about function argument initialization.  I'll delete my comment, thanks.

Comment: It's also worth noting that all this is still subject to the as-if rule, which "might" come into play in your example if heap elision kicks in. It will still never lead to a memory leak though.

Comment: @Frank could you elaborate further?

Comment: The compiler is free to reorder things as it pleases as long as the observable effects remain consistent. So the resulting code will not necessarily be in that actual order (as long as you can't tell without stepping through the assembly)

Comment: Don't know how true that is,  I'll wait for @T.C. to reply to that as they know more about this

Comment: Also @HowardHinnant can probably shed more light as well

Comment: It doesn't matter anyways. As long as your code doesn't contain any undefined behavior, and you are not in the process of micro-optimizing, you can generally ignore the as-if rule.

Comment: Even the _hardware_ is free to reorder things as long as the observable effects remain consistent, which is what makes coding with relaxed memory order atomics so entertaining. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Each member initialisation is treated as a separate statement, and the order between these statements is strictly defined.

So in your example, the order is going to be defined as:

1. new A{}
2. a{}
3. new int{3}
4. b{}
5. new C{}
6. c{}